# Can text edits in QuarkXPress automatically replicate in a linked text source file?

Tags: software-recommendation, text, quarkxpress

Is there a way to import a text file into Quark in such a way so that if there are any spelling errors that are fixed in Quark they will also be updated in the original imported text file?

Kind of like the way one can link an Excel file in a Word document.

Comment: I'm not sure the Excel in Word example is a good one. You'd either embed the Excel file within the Word file - there is then no external source file; or you link the Excel file in, in which case the changes are made in the Excel file, and the Word doc picks up the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. Publish/subscribe works the other way around. If corrections are made to the original, the XPress file is updated when opened.

I don't believe any layout app sends data back to the original file.

Comment: How about having the file read-only so that when modified outside of quark it will be updated?

Comment: Xpress doesn't send data like that. There's nothing that's going to read data which is not sent. A file is either set to publish or subscribe. Subscribe will update. Publish will not. Xpress **only subscribes** it does not publish where linked text is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this sort of workflow - two-way editing - is more within the scope of Quark's other products, like Quark Publishing System.